# How many exam papers earn a grade of $90%$

Tags: combinatorics

*It is an exercise question (#19) in the book with image showing all details.*

My answer is given below, & request vetting. $$\sum_{k=19}^{20} \binom{20}{x}\cdot 3^{(20-k)} $$
$$\binom{20}{19}\cdot 3^1 => 60$$
[image]

Comment: This is clearly not the way one is supposed to ask questions on MSE. Nontheless. the first formula you wrote is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it,  $(0.9 ) 20 = 18$, it should be

$$\sum_{k=\color{red}{18}}^{20} \binom{20}{x}\cdot 3^{(20-k)} $$

Comment: Thanks for pointing the error.

Comment: Please help with my post of today at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2903732/424260. It is regarding detailed analysis of the 'misapplication of the product principle'.

Comment: Please help with my last comment, as no response is there till now.

Comment: Is my earlier comment's post (for which I asked help) is obscure or incomprehensible; so that I need to restate it. I need help in that post, to clear up my understanding, & have failed to elicit any response so far.  Please tell me what it lacks.

Comment: Please tell something, as have lost hope on my solving it on my own. Also, that would be helpful to me as a guideline for future posts.

Comment: Can we chat on the issues concerning my stated post at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2903732/424260

Comment: I found it. Please see the update on the post & vet.

Comment: Am I committing some sort of behavioral error, that there is no response from you?

Comment: I am still outside of my house.