# Help needed with alternative approach to solve the problem of counting passwords.

Tags: combinatorics

*In the book titled 'Combinatorics- A Guided Tour' by David Majur', there is 
stated on [pg. #20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO1fa.png), the problem, as also stated below.*

> How many $8$ char. passwords are there if each character is either an uppercase letter $A-Z$, a lowercase letter $a-z$, or a digit $0-9$, & where at least one uppercase & at least one lowercase letter are used.

The shorter, easier & usual approach is to use the Inclusion - exclusion principle, & take help by taking complements, as below:

Take the complement of the case of : 'at least one upper-case letter' & 'at least one lower-case letter'. 
This leads to: $B ∪ C$; with $B$ = 'no upper-case letter'; $C$ = 'no lower-case letter'.

So, need take difference from the set of all possible passwords, leading to : $|A| - |B∪C|$.

Now, taking by inclusion-exclusion principle, the fact:
$|B∪C|= |B|+|C|-|B∩C|$, leading to $|A| - |B|-|C|+|B∩C|$. 
The values of $|A|, |B|, |C|, |B∩C|$ are:
$|A|= 62^8, |B|=36^8, |C|=36^8, |B∩C|=10^8$.
$|A| - |B|-|C|+|B∩C| = 62^8 - 36^8 - 36^8 + 10^8 = 212,697,985,769,984.$

---

> I wanted alternate approach that computes the actual passwords by applying product rule for each case, & then applying sum rule for adding up the different cases as shown below; but am unable to get the correct answer as shown below:

The cases are :
(a) At least one digit is there, e.g. 1Uppercase-1Lowercase-6Digit, denoted by 1U1L6D. All the options are:
(i)
$1U1L6D = 26^2\cdot 10^6$, permutations : 
$$1U2L5D, 2U1L5D = 26^3\cdot 10^5$$
$$1U3L4D, 3U1L4D = 26^4\cdot 10^4$$
$$1U4L3D, 4U1L3D = 26^5\cdot 10^3$$
$$1U5L2D, 5U1L2D = 26^6\cdot 10^2$$
$$1U6L1D, 6U1L1D = 26^7\cdot 10^1$$

=> $26^2\cdot 10^6+2\cdot (26^3\cdot 10^5 + 26^4\cdot 10^4 + 26^5\cdot 10^3 + 26^6\cdot 10^2 + 26^7\cdot 10^1)$

=> $259,512,830,720$

(b) No digit is there. All the options are:
$$1U7L, 7U1L = 26^8$$
$$2U6L, 6U2L = 26^8$$
$$3U5L, 5U3L = 26^8$$
$$4U4L = 26^8$$
$$5U3L, 3U5L = 26^8$$
$$6U2L, 2U6L = 26^8$$
$$7U1L, 1U7L = 26^8$$

=> $26^8\cdot 13 = 2,714,751,839,488$

The sum of the above two cases is: $259,512,830,720 + 2,714,751,839,488 = 2,974,264,670,208$.

---

*Update :* The responses have been incorporated in the below update:

(a) At least one digit is there, e.g. 1Uppercase-1Lowercase-6Digit, denoted by 1U1L6D. All the options are:
(i)

> $1U1L6D :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{1,1,6}$, ordering$ = 26^2\cdot 10^6$, permutations : $\binom{8}{1,1,6}26^2\cdot 10^6$, 
>   $1U2L5D, 2U1L5D :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{1,2,5}$, ordering$= 26^3\cdot 10^5$, permutations : $\binom{8}{1,2,5}26^3\cdot 10^5$, 
>   $1U3L4D, 3U1L4D :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{1,3,4}$, ordering$= 26^4\cdot 10^4$, permutations : $\binom{8}{1,3,4}26^4\cdot 10^4$, 
>   $1U4L3D, 4U1L3D :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{1,3,4}$, ordering$= 26^5\cdot 10^3$, permutations : $\binom{8}{1,3,4}26^5\cdot 10^3$, 
>   $1U5L2D, 5U1L2D :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{1,2,5}$, ordering$= 26^6\cdot 10^2$, permutations : $\binom{8}{1,2,5}26^6\cdot 10^2$, 
>   $1U6L1D, 6U1L1D $ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{1,1,6}$, ordering$= 26^7\cdot 10^1$, permutations : $\binom{8}{1,1,6}26^7\cdot 10^1$,

=> $\binom{8}{1,1,6}26^2\cdot 10^6 + 2\cdot (\binom{8}{1,2,5}26^3\cdot 10^5 + \binom{8}{1,3,4}26^4\cdot 10^4 + \binom{8}{1,3,4}26^5\cdot 10^3 + \binom{8}{1,2,5}26^6\cdot 10^2 + \binom{8}{1,1,6}26^7\cdot 10^1)$

==> $56\cdot 26^2\cdot 10^6$ + $2\cdot (168\cdot 26^3\cdot 10^5 + 0\cdot 26^4\cdot 10^4 + 280\cdot 26^5\cdot 10^3 + 168\cdot 26^6\cdot 10^ + 56\cdot 26^7\cdot 10^1)$

===> 37856000000+ $2\cdot (295276800000 + 1919299200000 + 3326785280000 + 5189785036800 + 4497813698560)$

====>$30,495,776,030,720$

> $2U2L4D :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{2,2,4}$, ordering$ = 26^4\cdot 10^4$, permutations : $\binom{8}{2,2,4}26^4\cdot 10^4$, 
>   $2U3L3D, 3U2L3D :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{3,2,3}$, ordering$= 26^5\cdot 10^3$, permutations : $\binom{8}{3,2,3}26^5\cdot 10^3$, 
>   $2U4L2D, 4U2L2D :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{2,2,4}$, ordering$= 26^6\cdot 10^2$, permutations : $\binom{8}{2,2,4}26^6\cdot 10^2$, 
>   $2U5L1D, 5U2L1D :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{1,2,5}$, ordering$= 26^7\cdot 10^1$, permutations : $\binom{8}{1,2,5}26^7\cdot 10^1$,

=> $\binom{8}{2,2,4}\cdot 26^4\cdot 10^4 + 2\cdot (\binom{8}{3,2,3}26^5\cdot 10^3 + \binom{8}{2,2,4}26^6\cdot 10^2 + \binom{8}{1,2,5}26^7\cdot 10^1)$

==> $420\cdot 26^4\cdot 10^4 +2\cdot ( 560\cdot 26^5\cdot 10^3 + 420\cdot 26^6\cdot 10^2 + 168\cdot 26^7\cdot 10^1)$

===> $1919299200000+ 2\cdot (6653570560000 + 12974462592000 + 22489068492800)$

====> $86153502489600$

> $3U3L2D :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{2,3,3}$, ordering$ = 26^6\cdot 10^2$, permutations : $\binom{8}{2,3,3}26^6\cdot 10^2$, 
>   $3U4L1D, 4U3L1D :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{3,4,1}$, ordering$= 26^7\cdot 10^1$, permutations : $\binom{8}{3,4,1}26^7\cdot 10^1$,

=> $560\cdot 26^6\cdot 10^2 + 2\cdot (280\cdot 26^7\cdot 10^1)$

==> $560\cdot (30891577600 + 80318101760)$

===> $560\cdot (111209679360) = 62277420441600$

Sum of all cases'  counts in (a) : $178926698961920$

(b) No digit is there. All the options are:

> $1U7L, 7U1L :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{1,7}$, ordering$ = 26^8$, permutations : $\binom{8}{1,7}\cdot 26^8$, 
>   $2U6L, 6U2L :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{2,6}$, ordering$ = 26^8$, permutations : $\binom{8}{2,6}\cdot 26^8$, 
>   $3U5L, 5U3L :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{3,5}$, ordering$ = 26^8$, permutations : $\binom{8}{3,5}\cdot 26^8$, 
>   $4U4L :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{4,4}$, ordering$ = 26^8$, permutations : $\binom{8}{4,4}\cdot 26^8$, 
>   $5U3L, 3U5L :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{3,5}$, ordering$ = 26^8$, permutations : $\binom{8}{3,5}\cdot 26^8$, 
>   $6U2L, 2U6L :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{2,6}$, ordering$ = 26^8$, permutations : $\binom{8}{2,6}\cdot 26^8$, 
>   $7U1L, 1U7L :$ sel. positns.:$\binom{8}{1,7}$, ordering$ = 26^8$, permutations : $\binom{8}{1,7}\cdot 26^8$,

=> $4\cdot(\binom{8}{1,7}\cdot 26^8 + \binom{8}{2,6}\cdot 26^8 + \binom{8}{3,5}\cdot 26^8) + (\binom{8}{4,4}\cdot 26^8)$

==> $4\cdot(8\cdot 26^8 + 28\cdot 26^8 + 56\cdot 26^8) + (70\cdot 26^8)$

===> $4\cdot(1670616516608 + 5847157808128+ 11694315616256) + (14617894520320)$

====> $4\cdot (19212089940992) + 14617894520320= 76848359763968 + 14617894520320 = 91466254284288$

---

Sum of all cases'  counts in (a) & (b) : $270,392,953,246,208$

Still mismatch is there as the sum crosses the correct value by $57,694,967,476,224$.

Comment: Your $U1L1D6=26^2\cdot 10^6$ isn't a correct counting of all ways to use one upper case letter, one lower case letter, and six digits. This method does not distinguish between all of the passwords which put the upper case letter first, then the lower case letter, then the six digits (there are $26^2\cdot 10^6$ ways of doing this), versus, for example, the ones which put the lower case letter first, then the digits, then the upper case letter (there are ANOTHER $26^2\cdot 10^6$ ways of doing this). The same comment applies to all your other cases.

Comment: Your enumeration of the cases must not only specify what types of characters occur in the password (how many upper case, how many lower case, and how many digits) but how those types of characters are ordered in the password. For example, with an 8 character password, 1 upper case letter, 1 lower case letter, and 6 digits, there would be $\binom{8}{1,1,6}=56$ ways to order those types of characters.

Comment: hmm...you might want to work on a simpler problem such as number of ways to sort $Aa111111$ and $Aa111222$ first though I don't encourage this sort of enumeration as it seems to take too much time.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I was also thinking of the same, as the sheer size is really too much. Better you define the problem, might be a smaller subset or whatever feels fit to you. I will take that problem as addendum, after the *Update* in OP.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Please suggest a smaller case, am waiting for your input.

Comment: you can make ur password length smaller to examine things and perhaps work on possible permutations on a particular pattern.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Can I have a brief chat on 'one' issue concerning this post, before taking up a smaller case of password of $3$ chars., & other conditions also modified by having Upper case letters / lower case ones from the set $(A,B,C,D), (a,b,c,d)$ respectively, & digits from the set $[1-4]$. However, there would be same constraint i.e. at least one upper-case letter & one lower-case letter. This would shorten the no. of possible passwords to max. of $4*4*4=64$.

Comment: sure, just start a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82785/discussion-between-jiten-and-siong-thye-goh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to use multiplicative principle to solve the problem is by using a recurrence relation.

Let $L[j]$ be the number of password of length $j$ that consists of at least $1$ lowercase letter and no uppercase letters at all.

We can  write down $L[j]=36^j - 10^j$ immediately.

Or we can do it the longer way by observing that $$L[0]=0$$ and by multiplicative principle, we have

$$L[j] = 36L[j-1]+26(10^{j-1}).$$

We can solve the recurrence as follows:

\begin{align}
L[j] &= 36L[j-1]+26(10^{j-1})\\
&=36^kL[j-k] + 26\sum_{r=0}^{k-1} 36^r(10^{j-1-r}) \\
&=26 \cdot 10^{j-1}\sum_{r=0}^{j-1} \left(\frac{36}{10} \right)^r \\
&= 26 \cdot 10^{j-1} \cdot\frac{\left( \frac{36}{10}\right)^j-1}{\frac{36}{10}-1} \\
&= 36^j - 10^j
\end{align}

That was a warm up.

Similarly, we define $U[j]$ be the number of password of length $j$ that consists of at least $1$ uppercase letter and no lowercase letters at all.

By symmetry, $L[j]=U[j]$.

Now, let's define $A[j]$ to be the password of length $j$ that consists of at least $1$ uppercase and at least one lowercase letter.

We have $A[0]=0$ and

$$A[j]=62A[j-1] + 26L[j-1] + 26U[j-1]$$

Again, we can solve the recurrence relation.

\begin{align}
A[j] &= 62A[j-1] + 52(36^{j-1}-10^{j-1}) \\
&= 62^k A[j-k] + 52 \sum_{r=0}^{k-1} 62^r(36^{j-1-r}-10^{j-1-r}) \\
&= 52 \sum_{r=0}^{j-1} 62^r(36^{j-1-r}-10^{j-1-r}) \\
&= 52 \left( 36^{j-1} \sum_{r=0}^{j-1}\left( \frac{62}{36}\right)^r- 10^{j-1}\sum_{r=0}^{j-1}\left( \frac{62}{10}\right)^r\right) \\
&= 52 \left( 36^{j-1}\cdot \frac{\left( \frac{62}{36}\right)^j-1}{\frac{62}{36}-1} - 10^{j-1}\cdot \frac{\left( \frac{62}{10}\right)^j-1}{\frac{62}{10}-1} \right) \\
&= 52 \left( 36^{j}\cdot \frac{\left( \frac{62}{36}\right)^j-1}{26} - 10^{j}\cdot \frac{\left( \frac{62}{10}\right)^j-1}{52} \right) \\
&= 2(62^j) - 2(36^j)-62^j +10^j \\
&= 62^j - 2(36^j) + 10^j
\end{align}

Comment: Please help with my today's post at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2912705/424260. I came into this topic while hoping that the topic introduced in our last chat (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82785/discussion-between-jiten-and-siong-thye-goh) was concerned with Stirling numbers, which is dealt by a new perspective (functional mapping) in the book of K. D. Joshi. The today's post is concerned with background needed to reach the topic of Stirling numbers in the stated book.

Comment: Please help with my post at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2912705/424260.

Comment: I hope that your answer could add more particularly to the Q.3. raised in my post referred in earlier comment.

Comment: I can look at your question later.

Answer (score 3):

By now you must appreciate the power of the Principle of Inclusion / Exclusion!  I can't resist pointing out that the problem can be solved even more simply with an exponential generating function (EGF).

The EGF for words formed with upper case letters and containing at least one letter is $(e^z)^{26}-1$.  The EGF for words formed with lower-case letters and containing at least one letter is the same.  The EGF for words formed with digits (0-9) is $(e^z)^{10}$.  So the EGF for words containing at least one upper case letter, at least one lower case letter, and zero or more digits is
$$\begin{align}
f(z) &= (e^{26z}-1)^2 \; e^{10z}\\
&= e^{62z} - 2 e^{36z} + e^{10z}
\end{align}$$
The number of ways to form an acceptable password of length 8 is the coefficient of $\frac{1}{8!} z^8$ in $f(z)$, which is 
$$\boxed{62^8 - 2 \times 36^8 + 10^8}$$

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed $26^2\cdot10^6$ possibilities for $1U1L6D$ when it comes to choosing the characters.

But how about the number of arrangements?

E.g. a561F324 is another password than 361aF542, right?

If the $6$ digits are distinct then there are $8!$ arrangements, but if e.g. they are all the same then there are $2\binom82$ arrangements.

So the $1U1L6D$ passwords must be subdivided again, and this time based on the diversity of the digits. Then for each situation you must find the number of arrangements.

That will be quite a job.

Reasons enough to be happy with inclusion/exclusion :-).

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing towards permutations.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: Kindly explain how you got the value of $2\binom82$ arrangements, if the $6$ digits are all the same.

Comment: First you select $2$ spots for the letters. There are $\binom82$ possibilities. But this must be taken twice because there are $2$ orders for the letters leading to different passwords. Another expression for this is $\frac{8!}{1!1!6!}$.

Comment: For permutations with $r$ types of elements with count: $n_1, n_2,\cdots, n_r$, the formula is $\frac{n!}{n_{1}!n_{2}!\cdot \cdot \cdot n_{r}!}$. That covers the ordering of the $2$ distinct letters, as given by $\frac{8!}{1!1!6!}$.  Otherwise, can take the combinations (spaces possible without ordering) of $2$ letters as: $\frac{8!}{6!\cdot 2!}$, and then multiply by orderings among the $2$ elements for $2$ spot, i.e. $2!$, leading to again : $2\binom82$. Please vet the updated comment.

Comment: Indeed. That is the general expression for it (under $n=n_1+\cdots+n_r$ of course).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing cases.  For instance, two uppercase letters, four lowercase letters, and two digits.  You have also not accounted for the positions of the various types of characters within the sequence.

To determine the total number of cases, let $x_d$, $x_l$, and $x_u$ denote, respectively, the number of digits, lowercase letters, and uppercase letters that appear in the sequence.  Then
$$x_d + x_l + x_u = 8 \tag{1}$$
The requirement that at least one uppercase and at least one lowercase letter appear in the sequence means $x_u \geq 1$ and $x_u \geq 1$.  Since there is no such requirement for the number of digits, $x_d \geq 0$.

Let $x_d' = x_d + 1$.  Then $x_d'$ is a positive integer.  Substituting $x_d' - 1$ for $x_d$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_d' - 1 + x_l + x_u & = 8\\
x_d' + x_l + x_u & = 9 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the positive integers.  A particular solution of equation  2 corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in the eight spaces between successive ones in a row of nine ones.
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
For instance, placing an addition in the third and fifth spaces yields
$$1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 1$$
which corresponds to the solution $x_d' = 3$ ($x_d = 2$), $x_l = 2$, $x_u = 4$.  Thus, the number of cases is the number of ways we can select two of the eight spaces to be filled with addition signs, which is 
$$\binom{9 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{8}{2} = 28$$

Also, you have to account for the positions of the characters.

For the case of four uppercase and four lowercase letters, you must multiply the $26^4$ ways of selecting the uppercase letters and the $26^4$ ways of selecting the lowercase letters by the $\binom{8}{4}$ ways to choose the positions of the upper case letters and $\binom{4}{4}$ ways of filling the remaining four positions with the lowercase letters, so there are 
$$\binom{8}{4}26^4\binom{4}{4}26^4$$
such arrangements.

For the case of two uppercase letters, four lowercase letters, and two digits, in addition to selecting two uppercase letters in $26^2$ ways, four lowercase letters in $26^4$ ways, and two digits in $10^2$ ways, you must choose two of the eight positions for the uppercase letters, four of the remaining six positions for the lowercase letters, and fill the remaining two positions with digits.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{8}{2}26^2 \cdot \binom{6}{4}26^4 \cdot \binom{2}{2}10^2$$
such arrangements.

Comment: If am not wrong, you have taken combinations (either by finding no. of multisets, or by finding the no. of combinations, in the cases (a) & (b) respectively) rather than permutations. Please correct me if wrong. Also, the taking of multisets is only justified if all Upper case letters, lower-case letters, and digits are indistinguishable in their respective category. This means that arrive at a larger value with multisets, than if had computed only the combinations.

Comment: Let's look at the case of two uppercase letters, four lowercase letters, and two digits.  I choose two positions for the uppercase letters, four positions for the lowercase letters, and two positions for the digits in $$\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{4}\binom{2}{2} = \binom{8}{2, 4, 2}$$ ways.  That accounts for the order in which the different types of characters appear.  The fact that characters may be repeated accounts for the $26$ choices for each position with an uppercase letter, $26$ choices for each position with a lowercase letter, and $10$ choices for each position with a digit.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating part (b) that finds the combinations (by finding positions), & then finding orderings in each group, leading effectively to permutations. But, would request elaboration for part (a) that concerns with multisets, which to me gives a larger value than choosing positions (i.e. combinations).

Comment: I do not follow.  Notice that $$\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{4}\binom{2}{2} = \frac{8!}{2!6!} \cdot \frac{6!}{4!2!} \cdot \frac{2!}{2!0!} = \frac{8!}{2!4!2!} = \binom{8}{2, 4, 2}$$ so choosing positions is equivalent to choosing multisets.  Or are you asking about the cases you overlooked?

Comment: Please check the update, & help as the sum of all cases now exceeds the actual.

Comment: You made some careless errors.  For instance, if we denote the cases by $(U, L, D)$, you counted the cases $(1, 1, 6)$, $(2, 2, 4)$, $(3, 3, 2)$, $(4, 4, 0)$ twice when you should have counted once.

Comment: I am sorry for my failure to understand, as it is clear that $(1,1,6)$ (or the other $3$ cases) means that already all possible permutations are taken. But, that yields only $33874333176320$ of which $37856000000$ by $(1,1,6)$, $1919299200000$ by $(2,2,4)$, $17299283456000$ by $(3,3,2)$, $14617894520320$ by $(4,4,0)$. The difference is $57032516895744 - 33874333176320 = 23158183719424$.

Comment: There were comptnl. errors in my OP, as shown by the case $(3,3,2)$. The changes shown by the $4$ cases specified by you have been accommodated. Still, there is difference as shown above, & in fact it has increased to $57,694,967,476,224$, due to higher (& correct) value of $(3,3,2)$. .